# Capture audio in zalenium

Tags: selenium, docker, video-capture, audio-capture, zalenium

How to capture audio along with video in zalenium.The commands on github of zalenium([link](https://github.com/zalando/zalenium)) only capture video.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zalenium uses VNC, which so far does not support audio, some additional things would need to be done like adding pulseaudio and another layer on top to put video and audio together. 
So, the short answer is: it is not possible.